# Configuring multiple Checkstyle checks for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

Does anyone know of a way to implement multiple checkstyle configurations at the same time within Eclipse?

So, to be clear -we already have the checkstyle plugin installed and configured.  We have standard checks already implemented (remotely, on a corporate level).  We'd like to add to the checks that are already configured.  Unfortunately, the current checks are uneditable.  Is there a way to implement a second configuration?

As far as I can figure out, it seems like you can only implement a single configuration at a time.  Hopefully, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Go to `Window → Preferences → Checkstyle` to add your own Checkstyle configuration.

Next, `right-click your Eclipse project → Properties → Checkstyle`. On the `Main` tab, uncheck `Use Simple Configuration` and click `Add` to add you new Checkstyle configuration. Be sure to use the same `File Set` for both configurations.

Now all files are checked with the rules from both configurations.

(I assumed "the checkstyle plugin" to be eclipse-cs.)